# Obtaining an iterator from the element passed to a lambda when using std::find_if

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, stl-algorithm

I am trying to simplify a recursive function that receives an iterator. Somewhere in the function it is necessary to search for an element matching a given condition in the range going from the iterator to the end of the vector. So, I thought I could use `find_if` as shown below:

```
typedef std::vector<Foo> FooVec;
FooVec v;

int f(FooVec::iterator it) {
  /* ... */
  auto it2 = std::find_if(it, end(v),
      [](const Foo& foo) {
        auto foo_it = /* obtain the corresponding iterator for foo. */
        return f(foo_it) == 0;
      });
  /* ... */
}
```

But the lambda function receives an element, not an iterator to the current element, so I cannot easily call `f` again. I could search for `foo` in `v` in order to get the iterator, but that would be inefficient. Alternatively I could just use a regular `for` loop with the iterators. But I was wondering whether there is the possibility to use `find_if` in this situation.

Comment: It is unclear what is the purpose of function f.

Comment: Get rid of  the global variable 'v'  (it might be no global, but the usage is similar), and pass that v directly to your recursive function (then you might capture 'v' in the lambda).

Comment: I feel like this is a case of the XY Problem.

Comment: In my code base, I have an adapter that takes an iterator range, and produces a range over the iterators in the range (excluding end).  It isn't *hard* to write, but without a library (like `boost` or home rolled) it is a bit tedious.  I also have a range-based `find_if` -- between the two, `auto it2 = linear_search_if( iterators_of( it, end(v) ), [](FooVec::iterator foo){ /* blah */ } );`  I don't consider this an answer, because it doesn't describe how to write `linear_search_if` or `iterators_of`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Messy, but `v.begin() + (&foo - &v.front())` is the iterator pointing to `foo`. Note that this only works because `vector` has contiguous storage: don't try it with a `list` or `deque`.

Comment: I was thinking of something along these lines. I was hoping for some C++ magic :) But, I suppose this is the best it can get, right? I wonder if it's just better to use a regular loop with iterators...

Comment: `v.data()` instead of `&v.front()`

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would just write the loop myself. (Yeah, I know, I usually say to use the algorithms, but this seems like a case where doing it yourself is easier).

Uncompiled code follows:

```
for ( auto iter = it; iter != end(v); ++iter )
{
// *iter is the value; iter is the iterator
// if you have to search to the end, you can use [iter, end(v))
}
```

Works with all containers: vector, list, deque, etc.